# SQL to convert date from one format to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `dateofbirth_string` which is a VARCHAR containing dates in format dd/mm/yyyy. I would like to convert these values into format DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) and place in field `dateofbirth_date` in the same row.

Note, some values in `dateofbirth_string` may be in a bad format e.g. 10/02/15 or 100215. For these values, they can be ignored and I will enter manually.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**STR_TO_DATE** is your goal.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2020', '%d/%c/%Y');
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2020', '%d/%c/%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2020', '%d/%c/%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2020-04-22                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```